# Where does a variable passed to Reqwest's Result::read_to_string get the data from?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am learning Rust and have been playing around with this example to perform an HTTP GET request and then display the data:

```
extern crate reqwest;
use std::io::Read;

fn run() -> Result<()> {
    let mut res = reqwest::get("http://httpbin.org/get")?;
    let mut body = String::new();
    res.read_to_string(&mut body)?;

    println!("Status: {}", res.status());
    println!("Headers:\n{:#?}", res.headers());
    println!("Body:\n{}", body);

    Ok(())
}
```

I cannot understand how the variable `body` is actually ending up with the correct data. For headers and status, I can see the associated functions but for the body data it just uses `read_to_string` for the whole data?

Comment: Please, read the Rust basis in the book. `&mut body` allows the function to modify `body` without owning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `res` object has a `read_to_string()` method which stores the response into the `String` that you pass it in

```
res.read_to_string(&mut body);
```

Edit: imported from my comment:

[reqwest::Response 0.6.2 documentation](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.6.2/reqwest/struct.Response.html) states for `Read` for `Response`:

> Read the body of the Response

which somehow seems missing from the documentation of the current version.

Comment: See thats whats confusing me , the response from the GET request should contain the Status Code , Headers and body yet when you print the response that has been stored in res its only the body content so surely somewhere there is some 'filtering'

Comment: [reqwest::Response 0.6.2 documentation](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.6.2/reqwest/struct.Response.html) states for `Read` for `Response`: *Read the body of the Response* which somehow seems missing from the documentation of the current version.

Comment: ah that makes more sense. Thanks so much